# Does InterSystems IRIS support one-to-one relationships?

Tags: data-modeling, intersystems-iris

Does InterSystems IRIS support one-to-one relationships in the object model?

I referred to the documentation, but it says only something about one-to-many and parent-child relationship types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! But it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

See this reply [for details](https://community.intersystems.com/post/do-we-have-one-one-relationships-iris#comment-151841) and a [simple example](https://community.intersystems.com/post/do-we-have-one-one-relationships-iris#comment-151856).

Comment: Thank you @Robert.c.c. But in fact, this means that it doesn't, but this could be managed with several approaches. Thanks for your answer.